# zsh: command not found for all installed programs

Tags: zsh

I'm using zsh as my shell on mac OS M1 Pro Monterrey. When I echo my path I get

```bash
/Users/vcui/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/vcui/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/vcui/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However typing in any commands like `node` or `nvm` gives me "zsh: command not found". My `~/.zshrc` starts with

```bash
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
```

I've also first sourced my ~/.zshrc before running `node` or `nvm`.

Since I have the PATH specified in my ~/.zshrc, why are all of the program commands unrecognized?

Comment: Removed the inappropriate `Bash` tag.

Comment: Which directory contains `node` and `nvm`? Based on your PATH, `ls` should be found. Does this also produce a _command not found_ error?

Comment: For debugging, forget for a moment your .zshrc. The interesting point is that the PATH shown at the command line contains `/usr/bin`, and on the MAC, this should contain `ls`. First verify that `ls` is there, and debug on the command line, why the file is not found. For the safe side, you could do a `rehash`, though for `ls` this should not be necessary.